# Проблема в дебиан 9 strech, не могу установить virtualbox через Apper

Tags: linux, debian

Недавно установил операционную систему Linux Debian 9 Strech. Хотел установить виртуальную машину - Virtualbox через менеджер пакетов Apper. Нахожу Virtualbox. Нажимаю Применить. Вылезает такое окошко:

> Не удаётся найти зависимость пакета. Дополнительная информация
>   доступна в детальном отчёте.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Кто знает в чем может быть причина и как ее решить? Подскажите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен. Всем мира.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -i
```

И теперь строка за строкой:

```
echo deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian "$(lsb_release -cs)" contrib non-free '#VirtualBox' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

GPG_KEY_DOWNLOAD_URL=$(curl --silent http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/virtualbox.repo | grep gpgkey | cut -d '=' -f 2)
wget "$GPG_KEY_DOWNLOAD_URL" -O - | apt-key add -

wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O - | apt-key add -

wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O - | apt-key add -

apt update

LATEST_VERSION=$(aptitude search -F %p --sort version virtualbox- | tail -1 | sed 's/:i386//' | tr -d ' ')

apt -y install "$LATEST_VERSION"
```

Comment: зачем плохому-то учить, злому и преходящему, вместо [хорошего, доброго, вечного](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/virtualbox)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, что плохого в официальной репе от разрабов приложения? Или они типа умеют писать виртуализацию, но не умеют собирать deb-пакеты? Я юзаю эту репу, когда в названии адреса cdn было "*sun*". Никогда проблем не было. А вот с "оф. сборками" от каноникла - ловил баги пару раз.

Comment: для дистрибутива этот репозиторий такой же «официальный», как и любая другая файлопомойка.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не соглашусь. Одно дело - когда у себя собирает Вася Пупкин и там хз что может приехать (с последующими поломками) по зависимостям. И другое - когда собирают прям разрабы.

Comment: *не соглашусь* — в каком месте я соврал? (ну, если не придираться к лирическим эпитетам). цитирую: «*для дистрибутива этот репозиторий такой же «официальный», как и любая другая файлопомойка*»

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ок. Задам вопрос по-другому. Чем плоха репа с прогой от разрабов проги?

Comment: я не могу вводить эти команды

Comment: @donRumata, вы не в ту плоскость пытаетесь меня увести. повторяю: это **не** официальный репозиторий **дистрибутива**. соответственно, с точки зрения пользователя **дистрибутива** ничем не хуже и не лучше **любой** другой файлопомойки. повторяю: **не хуже и не лучше**. просто *ещё одна* файлопомойка.

Comment: чтобы ещё приблизиться к той плоскости, в которой лежит факт о неофициальности, попробуйте ответить на вопрос: почему файлы, о которых речь, находятся на сервере компании (oracle, или кому там нынче акции принадлежат?), а не на сервере проекта debian?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я запутался. Так "учить, злому" или "не хуже и не лучше"? По поводу "почему не в главной репе?" Да банальное нежеление бодаться с внутренними требованими к каким-нить оформительским штукам дистра.

Comment: @Пользователь, почему?

Comment: @donRumata, 1. у́чите — плохому: использованию файлопомоек. 2. охохо… «главная(!) репа». «про каких заек??? какая ещё главная???». 3. «банальное нежеление бодаться с внутренними требованими к каким-нить оформительским штукам дистра» — ну это фантазия вообще за гранью добра и зла. и вот такими мифами полны интернеты… как страшно жить! уйду я от вас!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, "ну это фантазия вообще за гранью добра и зла" ну вот как-то забыл спросить у Оракла почему они не пушат напрямую в пэкэджес.дебиан.орг. Поэтому просто предположение. Я думал это понятно, раз нет пруфлинка. "охохо… «главная(!) репа»". Т.е. http://deb.debian.org/ не главная?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, так что плохого в файлопомойках?

Comment: @donRumata не знаю но я не могу ввести (sudo -i ) выходит ошибка ,, debian is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.,,

Comment: @Пользователь, ну значит у тебя не хватает прав для текущего пользователя. Разберись сначала с этим.

Comment: @Пользователь а подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: @donRumata можно с вами связаться в телеграмме?Или в других соц.сетях

Comment: @Пользователь все доступные способы связи у меня в профиле. И я не вижу сильных преимуществ над любым чатом и чатом встроенным в двиг этого сайта. В чём проблема общаться тут?

Comment: @donRumata нет проблем,подскажите как это сделать?(имеется ввиду ну значит у тебя не хватает прав для текущего пользователя. Разберись сначала с этим)

Comment: Или добавить свою учётку в группы `adm`, `sudo`. А как ты до этого софт ставил?